# DIVI Theme customizer changes not applied on existing pages

Tags: theme-customizer, localhost

I'm using the **Divi** theme on a localhost created by **WAMP Server**.

The changes I make using the theme customizer menu are updated correctly in the preview screen (header, background colour, logo size, etc)

But when I view the frontend none of these changes are saved or updated.

There are no plugins installed, and refreshing the page makes no difference.

Only the changes I made using the theme customizer aren't being displayed.

Also, when I add a new page the changes are applied on it, but not for old pages.

Comment: You need to contact Divi support, however this sounds like some kind of caching issue

Answer (score 2):

Before you try following methods, I request you to clear you browser cache or disable any cache plugin and try again.

There is a functionality in divi which enables it to cache inline CSS and serve it as static CSS. If you disable this option, everything should work like charm!

**Go to Divi > Theme Options > Builder > Advanced >
Disable Static CSS File Generation**